# Что означает "synchronize_session" в sqlalchemy delete запросах? Вопросы по удалению в sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

По ходу разбора/изменения чужого кода возникают ошибки при синхронизации зависимых сущностей (Person - Child) по ходу скрипта синхронизации. Видимо, возникает такая ситуация, что `session.add(person)` пытается добавить в базу тот orm-Child-объект, который был удален синхронизатором ранее:

```
  session.add(person)
  File "/home/web/portal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1559, in add
    self._save_or_update_state(state)
  File "/home/web/portal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1578, in _save_or_update_state
    self._save_or_update_impl(st_)
  File "/home/web/portal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1828, in _save_or_update_impl
    self._update_impl(state)
  File "/home/web/portal/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1814, in _update_impl
    state_str(state)
InvalidRequestError: Instance '<Child at 0xec10afec>' has been deleted.  Use the make_transient() function to send this object back to the transient state.
```

1. Что означает пометить объект `make_transient()` - как и для чего это надо использовать в таком контексте?
2. По ходу кода используется и другая стратегия удаления объектов одним запросом:  через `.delete()`. Вопрос — что в таких запросах дает и когда используется флаг `synchronize_session`?

`session.query(Child).filter(Child.id==child.id).delete(synchronize_session=False)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Команда `session.query(Child).delete()` не только удалит соответствующие объектам `Child` записи из базы данных, но и обновит состояние этих объектов в сессии. Естественно, эти дополнительные действия требуют времени и соответственно замедлят процесс удаления. Если вы точно знаете, что дальше по коду вы не будете больше обращаться к этим объектам, то вам незачем обновлять их состояние. Для этого и служит `synchronize_session=False`. Но судя по возникающим у вас ошибкам, вы к ним всё-таки обращаетесь. Поэтому уберите параметр `synchronize_session` из `delete()` и проверьте, возникает ли проблема.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я вцелом разобрался, оставил удаление с synchronize_session = False, почистил из кода лишние flush на всякий случай. Проблема на продкшн оказалась вообще не в этом, а в том что на тестовом сервере не выключили отправку ошибок в общий пулл вместе с продакш-нскими и парралельно какоето время работал еще один синхронизатор со своей базой.